# Tensorflow : could not a find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensor

I am try to install tensorflow through pip but it showing error "could not a find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow"

Python 3.12.0

pip 23.3.1

i tried this cmd:
python3 -m pip install tensorflow

but this give a error: "Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases."

Comment: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip - "Software requirements: Python 3.9–3.11"

Comment: `py -m pip install tensorflow` or `python -m pip install tensorflow`

Answer (score 0):

You are using an incompatible version of Python (3.12.0) and TensorFlow
Check this link: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source
If you check the link you will see that you can install tensorflow on python2.7 as well but you just need to pick up the right combination.